# automated testing with Watir (or WatiN or similar): Disambiguating Select Elements

Tags: browser, automation, watin, watir, web-testing

**Problem:** I am looking for a way to run a test that is able to disambiguate between select controls that have the same value in more than one place.

**Example:**

I am trying to choose the third "monday" from a select control

```
ie.select_list( :id , 'choose-day' ).set( '-monday' );
```

where the select control has a kind of "outline" format in the control itself:

```
alice
-monday
-tuesday
bob
-monday
-tuesday
charlie
-monday
-tuesday
```

Given that the text is identical (and I do not know what the option values are ahead of time) is there a way to code the test such that the monday under charlie is the one that gets selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could use element_by_xpath to find the option you want, with something like this:

```
//select/option[text()='charlie']/following::option[text()='-monday']
```

then you could check the value attribute of that option (not sure how to do this in Watir), and select it using:

```
ie.select_list( :id , 'choose-day' ).select_value( whatever_the_value_was );
```

Answer (score 4):

In WatiN you can make use of multiple attribute support to match an element (I thought something similar is also available in Watir).

Option option = ie.SelectList("choose-day").Options(Find.ByText("-monday") && Find.ByIndex(2))

(index is zero based so 2 will give the third match (if any)).

HTH,
Jeroen van Menen
Lead dev WatiN